# Iterate lines through bulk string with go

Tags: string, go

I have a bulk of string that has two columns split by space, first columns is username and second column is password. I want to format that string to a slice of `User` struct

The string is like this:

```
 Bob qqweq
 Tom erwwe
 Andersen sadfadfs
```

The struct is simply like this:

```
type User struct{
  Username string
  Password string
}
```

How to do that typically with go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var users []User
for _, l := range strings.Split(s, "\n") {
    f := strings.Fields(l)
    if len(f) == 2 {
        users = append(users, User{f[0], f[1]})
    }
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/bXGJ6VKylT)</kbd>